# matching two character vectors in R with lapply

Tags: r, vector, match

I want to match items from two character vectors, "A" and "B", two find out two things: 1) whether items from vector A appear in vector B (yes/no) and 2) which items from vector B do not appear in vector A?

The two vectors look like this:

```
A <- c("i", "u", "I", "U", "E", "V", "@", "{", "$", "#", "Q", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
B <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "#", "$", "$", "1", "2", "2", "1", "d", "d", "i", "i", "i", "i", "1", "3", "2", "2", "F", "2", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "@", "5", "6", "5", "z", "z", "S", "S")
```

I can partially answer my first question with this function:

```
test_match <- function(item_vector_A, item_vector_B){
ifelse(item_vector_A == item_vector_B, print(1), print(0))
}

lapply(A, B, FUN = test_match) -> results
```

However, when I try this, I get a list of each comparison the function has made:

```
lapply(A, B, FUN = test_match) -> results
results
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#etc.
```

How can I get just a simple list that indicates for each item in A whether it occurs in B (1) or not (0), like this:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

I have the same problem when I try to answer my second question:

```
test_non_match <- function(item_vector_A, item_vector_B){
ifelse(item_vector_B == item_vector_A, print("*match*"), print(item_vector_B))
}
lapply(A, B, FUN = test_non_match) -> results2
results2
[[1]]
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "#"  "$" "$" "1" "2" "2" "1" "d" "d" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "1" "3" "2" "2" "F" "2" "2" "2" "5" "5" "5" "@" "5" "6" "5" "z" "z" "S" "S"      
[[2]]
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "#" "$" "$" "1" "2" "2" "1" "d" "d" "i" "i" "i" "i" "1" "3" "2" "2" "F" "2" "2" "2" "5" "5" "5" "@" "5" "6" "5" "z" "z" "S" "S"
[[3]]
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "#" "$" "$" "1" "2" "2" "1" "d" "d" "i" "i" "i" "i" "1" "3" "2" "2" "F" "2" "2" "2" "5" "5" "5" "@" "5" "6" "5" "z" "z" "S" "S"
```

It lists the whole vector, whereas I would like to have something like this:

```
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] d
[1] d
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] F
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] *match*
[1] z
[1] z
[1] S
[1] S
```

Do I need to use another type of apply() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `%in%` and test for `A %in% B` and `!(B %in% A )`. To reproduce the output in your question:

```
as.numeric(A %in% B)
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

and as suggested by Ferdinand.kraft:

```
ifelse (B %in% A, "*match*", B)
 [1] "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "d"       "d"       "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*"
[20] "*match*" "*match*" "F"       "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*"  "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "*match*" "z"       "z"       "S"       "S"
```

Comment: Why not simply `ifelse (B %in% A, "*match*", B)`?

Comment: True, really no need for `mapply` here! I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the alternatives above, you might want to take a look at %chin% which is a faster version of %in% in the data.table package:

```
ifelse (B %chin% A, "*match*", B)
```